# Newman: Getting authenticated error when running URL collection

Tags: postman-collection-runner, newman

I'm trying to run with `Newman` an existing collection URL on `Postman` but I'm getting an authentication error.

I'have tried according to [Newman documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/) to run a  URL collection. 
If I export the collection locally and run it, it works perfectly but when I change the local (exported JSON file) for the remote URL I'm getting the following **authentication error**:

```
error: You are not authenticated by the server.

workspace' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is what it works:

```
newman run pathToMyExportedLocallyCollection.json -e pathToMyExportedLocallyEnvironment.json
```

Instead, this gives me authentication the error:

```
newman run "https://myTemaName.postman.co/collections/myCollection" -e pathToMyExportedLocallyEnvironment.json
```

It makes sense to get an authentication error as this is not a public collection but I don't see any option in which I can specify user and password in order to get authenticated.

**Solved**:

@ Danny Dainton in his comment pointed me out this link: [Using Newman with the Postman API](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#using-newman-with-the-postman-api) which are just 5 steps to get access to the URL remotely with Postman API. Once you have performed those steps you are bale to do this:

```
$ newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/$uid?apikey=$apiKey" \
--environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/$uid?apikey=$apiKey"
```

Comment: Which type of URL are you using? The one created within the app or is it a Postman API URL (https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?version=latest) ?

Comment: Is the one that Postman provides me to get access to my team collection. For instance If I navigate that collection via browser instead of Postman Application. I will update my post and check the documentation that you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: This is what you might after - https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#using-newman-with-the-postman-api

Comment: The last Post was definitely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help!